# How to get the rand() function in excel to rerun when accessing an excel file through python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to access an excel file using python for my physics class. I have to generates data that follows a function but creates variance so it doesn’t line up perfectly to the function(simulating the error experienced in experiments). I did this by using the rand() function. We need to generate a lot of data sets so that we can average them together and eliminate the error/noise creates by the rand() function. I tried to do this by loading the excel file and recording the data I need, but then I can’t figure out how to get the rand() function to rerun and create a new data set. In excel it reruns when i change the value of any cell on the excel sheet, but I don’t know how to do this when I’m accessing the file with Python. Can someone help me figure out how to do this? Thank You.

Comment: if I understand this correctly, you need to generate some random data in python and or pandas? have you looked at `numpy` ? this is an excellent library for generating random data. https://www.numpy.org/

Comment: I need to generate the random numbers in excel and access them from the excel file using python. I can’t figure out how to get the random numbers to regenerate so I can get multiple data sets. Tbh what I’m trying to do could be accomplished with just python and numpy but I’m trying to use pandas/xlrd/xlwt to access the excel file and do it through an excel file.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I doubt that this is viable. After all, Excel is a closed-source software and `pd.read_excel` may be called on a machine that does not have Excel installed. I second the `numpy` recommendation.

Comment: Yeah you’re probably right. I asked because I read so much documentation and couldn’t figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel formulas like RAND(), or any other formula, will only refresh when Excel is actually running and recalculating the worksheet.

So, even though you may be access the **data** in an Excel workbook with Python, you won't be able to run Excel calculations that way. You will need to find a different approach.

Comment: Aww that’s what I was afraid of. Yeah I can use Visual Basic instead. Thanks